# Creating new activity gives error "Performing pause of activity that is not resumed"

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have created several activities via `Intent`'s in the past, yet this error baffles me.

This is a simple tutorial given on [Developer.Android](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)'s website for creating a new `Activity`

**Problem:**

The error is thrown before `onPause()` and after calling `startActivityForResult()` all in the same `Activtiy`

**Error:**

```
E/ActivityThread: Performing pause of activity that is not resumed: {wrap302.nmu.assignment_6_task_2_server/wrap302.nmu.assignment_6_task_2_server.MainActivity}
            java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing pause of activity that is not resumed: {wrap302.nmu.assignment_6_task_2_server/wrap302.nmu.assignment_6_task_2_server.MainActivity}
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3398)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3386)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3361)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap13(ActivityThread.java)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5471)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static String isHost = "isHost";

    private Context mContext;
    private Button btnHostGame;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnHostGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHostGame);
        btnHostGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startGameActivity(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void startGameActivity(boolean isHosting) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GameConnector.class);
        intent.putExtra(isHost, isHosting);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);    //Exception occurs after this method
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getActionBar().hide();
    }

    // Exception occurs before this method is called
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Did you win?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is quite strange to me, any advice?

**UPDATE**

AndroidManifest request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="wrap302.nmu.assignment_6_task_2_server">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/title_game">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name=".GameConnector"
                android:label="@string/title_gameconnector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name=".Game"
                android:label="@string/title_game">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

yes, `GameConnector` does get created without a problem.

However, the `Exception` is thrown *before* the `GameConnector.onCreate` method is called.

**UPDATE 2**

GameConnector code request

```
public class GameConnector extends Activity implements FragmentFinishListener{

    public static String GameType = "GameType", GameConnect = "GameConnect";
    public static String PlayerName = "PlayerName";
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private Fragment gameTypeFragment;
    private Intent gameIntent;
    private boolean isHosting;
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gameconnector);
        mContext = this;
        gameIntent = getIntent();

        if (gameIntent.hasExtra(MainActivity.isHost))
            isHosting = gameIntent.getBooleanExtra(MainActivity.isHost, false);
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        gameTypeFragment = (isHosting)
                ? new FragmentHostGame().setOnFragmentFinishListener(this)
                : new FragmentJoinGame().setOnFragmentFinishListener(this);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, gameTypeFragment, GameType);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void finished(Bundle bundle) {
        GameConnection gameConnection = null;
        if (bundle != null){
            if (bundle.containsKey(GameConnect))
                gameConnection = (GameConnection) bundle.getSerializable(GameConnect);
        }
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(gameTypeFragment).commit();

        startGame(isHosting, gameConnection);
    }

    private void startGame(boolean isHosting, GameConnection gameConnection) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Game.class);
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.isHost, isHosting);
        intent.putExtra(GameConnect, gameConnection);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (data != null){
            switch (requestCode){
                case 0:{
                    if (resultCode == 0){
                        finishActivity(resultCode);
                    }
                    else {
                        setResult(resultCode, data);
                        finishActivity(1);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        setResult(resultCode, null);
        finishActivity(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is `startGameActivity()` called?

Comment: @Ramanlfc see update

Comment: surely this doesn't compile without a cast `btnHostGame = findViewById(R.id.btnHostGame);`

Comment: @Ramanlfc it does compile perfectly, although I am not sure why a cast is required at times. Maybe calls for another SO question?

Comment: @Ramanlfc I shall add a cast for the sake of it

Comment: Please post your manifest. Does `GameConnector.onCreate()` get called?

Comment: @DavidWasser please see update

Comment: Please post the code in the constructor of the `GameConnector`. Also any code that would be executed when the `GameConnector` is constructed (for example , any member variable or static variable initializations).

Comment: @DavidWasser updated, let me know if you need anything else. The fragments do not have a `default constructor` of my own creation as this is strongly advised against.

Comment: I am baffled. Do you see anything in the logcat that would indicate the `GameConnector` is crashing BEFORE `onCreate()` is called? Don't filter the logcat as you might miss something important. I don't see any problem in the code you've posted. You wrote that this is a minimal example. Perhaps there is other code that is causing the problem? I don't know what to suggest from here. Very strange

Comment: @DavidWasser thank you for taking the time to solve the problem. I am still busy working on some network communications for my app. When I have completed it, I shall run again and try to source a possible issue. I shall tag you if I find something